# For Selenium, how would I send a multi-line command through the console of the browser through selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium on python right now and I was wondering how to execute multi line commands to the console
I am doing this command:

```
script = "alert('Test Alert')"
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Although I'm not sure how to make it so I can paste a multi-line piece of code for it to execute in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to execute the multiline command in the same way like single-line:

```
script = '''
    a = function(b, c) {
        return b + c;
    }
    
    return a(2, 2);
'''

print(driver.execute_script(script))
```

this will print `4`.

However, if you'll run the script with alert, the browser will be blocked until the alert is closed.

Please note, for this script:

```
script = '''
    a = function(b, c) {
        return b + c;
    }
    alert('Test Alert');
    return a(2, 2);
'''

print(driver.execute_script(script))
```

this will print `None`, but `return a(2, 2)` line will be also executed;

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you so much, can verify that for python 3.9+ a method like this works just fine!